# How to find the greatest and least possible values of modulus of z

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, locus

I need help with question 22 where I can't seem to understand the usage of the least possible values of modulus of z same as in question 20 where it does not make sense to me what it means geometrically how I find it?

[image: Question 20 and 22]

Comment: modulus $z =$ distance between $(0,0)$ and the point $z$ on the line

Comment: But where is z?

Comment: like if you where to draw them geometrically how do i find the least point of z

Comment: Whoever wrote this problem should be ashamed of how unclear it is. After looking at it for a while, I realize the idea is that $z$ (a.k.a. $P$) refers to generic points on the open ray with endpoint $-3 + 0i$ and passing through $0 + 3\sqrt 3 i$. Part (a) is to write an equation for the ray. (I assume you may express $z$ in terms of some arbitrary parameter $t$. Be sure to include the inequality needed to get only points on the ray, not the whole line.) Parts (b) and (c) involve finding the closest point on that ray to the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the first question, note that $|z-1|$ is the distance between the points $z$ and $1.$ Thus, $|z-1|=2$ is the equation for the circle of radius $2,$ centered at $1.$ If you draw a picture, it should be clear which point on the circle is closest to $0$--that is, has the least modulus--and which point is farthest from $0$--that is, has the greatest modulus.

In the case of the second question, I must agree with Paul Sinclair's comment: it is very poorly written--in particular, the word "a" is misleading. I'd start by finding the equation of a line in the plane with $x$-intercept $-3$ and $y$-intercept $3\sqrt3.$ Once you've found that, note that we require $x>-3,$ so you'll have something like $$y=mx+b,x>-3.$$ Now, note/recall that when $z=x+iy,$ we have $x=\frac{z+\bar z}2$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}.$ Substituting these into the equation and inequality above should let you describe the locus of points. Note that the point $z$ with the least modulus in the set will be the point closest to $0.$ In particular, we'll be able to draw a circle centered at $0$ such that the ray is tangent to the circle at the point $z.$ Put another way, the segment from $0$ to $z$ will be perpendicular to the ray, so the point $z$ will lie on the line $y=-\frac1mx,$ where $m$ is as above. (Do you see why?) Now, find the point $(a,b)$ such that $b=mx+a$ and $b=-\frac1ma,$ whence you'll have $z=a+ib,$ and from there you can find the modulus and argument of $z.$

Comment: Thank You!!!! Cameron Buie